# How to detect Face using emgu CV from Access database?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Please I need help
I try to make face recognition using emgu CV and it's working fine if i get data from windows folder but if i try to get data from database it's not working so what's the problem

this code to reading the stored images from a Windows Folder

```
    Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    'Load haarcascades for face detection
    face = New HaarCascade("face.xml")
    'eye = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_eye.xml");
    Try
        'Load of previus trainned faces and labels for each image
        Dim Labelsinfo As String = File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath & "/TrainedFaces/TrainedLabels.txt")
        'INSTANT VB NOTE: The variable Labels was renamed since Visual Basic does not handle local variables named the same as class members well:
        Dim Labels_Conflict() As String = Labelsinfo.Split("%"c)
        NumLabels = Convert.ToInt16(Labels_Conflict(0))
        ContTrain = NumLabels
        Dim LoadFaces As String

        Dim tf As Integer = 1
        Do While tf < NumLabels + 1
            LoadFaces = "face" & tf & ".bmp"
            FaceImg.Add(New Image(Of Gray, Byte)(Application.StartupPath & "/TrainedFaces/" & LoadFaces))
            FaceName.Add(Labels_Conflict(tf))
            tf += 1
        Loop


    Catch e As Exception

        MessageBox.Show("Nothing in binary database, please add at least a face(Simply train the prototype with the Add Face Button).", "Triained faces load", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    End Try
    End Sub
```

and this code to recognition

```
   Private Sub FrameGrabber(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    


    label3.Text = "0"
    'label4.Text = "";
    NamePersons.Add("")


    'Get the current frame form capture device
    currentFrame = grabber.QueryFrame().Resize(320, 240, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC)

    'Convert it to Grayscale
    gray = currentFrame.Convert(Of Gray, Byte)()

    'Face Detector
    Dim facesDetected()() As MCvAvgComp = gray.DetectHaarCascade(face, 1.2, 10, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, New Size(20, 20))

    'Action for each element detected
    For Each f As MCvAvgComp In facesDetected(0)
        t = t + 1
        result = currentFrame.Copy(f.rect).Convert(Of Gray, Byte)().Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC)
        'draw the face detected in the 0th (gray) channel with blue color
        currentFrame.Draw(f.rect, New Bgr(Color.Red), 2)


        If FaceImg.ToArray().Length <> 0 Then

            'TermCriteria for face recognition with numbers of trained images like maxIteration
            Dim termCrit As New MCvTermCriteria(ContTrain, 0.001)

            'Eigen face recognizer
            Dim recognizer As New EigenObjectRecognizer(FaceImg.ToArray(), FaceName.ToArray(), 3000, termCrit)

            name_Conflict = recognizer.Recognize(result)

            'Draw the label for each face detected and recognized
            currentFrame.Draw(name_Conflict, font_Conflict, New Point(f.rect.X - 2, f.rect.Y - 2), New Bgr(Color.LightGreen))
        End If

        NamePersons(t - 1) = name_Conflict
        NamePersons.Add("")


        'Set the number of faces detected on the scene
        label3.Text = facesDetected(0).Length.ToString()


    Next f
    t = 0

    'Names concatenation of persons recognized
    Dim nnn As Integer = 0
    Do While nnn < facesDetected(0).Length
        names = names & NamePersons(nnn) & ", "
        nnn += 1
    Loop
    'Show the faces procesed and recognized
    CamImageBox.Image = currentFrame
    label4.Text = names
    names = ""
    'Clear the list(vector) of names
    NamePersons.Clear()

End Sub
```

the problem is when I try to recognition faces from Access database
I only get the rectangle on the face without the name

this code I used to reading the stored images from Access Database

```
    Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    'Load haarcascades for face detection
    face = New HaarCascade("face.xml")
    'eye = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_eye.xml");
    Try


        RefreshDBConnection()
        Dim bitimage As Bitmap


        Dim numofrows As Integer = 0
        If TSTable.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
            numofrows = TSTable.Rows.Count
        End If




        For i As Integer = 0 To numofrows - 1

            Dim fetchedBytes() As Byte = CType(TSTable.Rows(i)("FaceImage"), Byte())
            Dim stream As New MemoryStream(fetchedBytes)
            bitimage = New Bitmap(stream)

            FaceImg.Add(New Emgu.CV.Image(Of Gray, Byte)(bitimage))



            Dim faceName_Conflict As String = CStr(TSTable.Rows(i)("FaceName").ToString)
            FaceName.Add(faceName_Conflict)
        Next i




    Catch e As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Nothing in binary database, please add at least a face(Simply train the prototype with the Add Face Button).", "Triained faces load", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Waiting for help

Regards

Comment: After you read data into a Memory Stream the stream is at EOF.  So you have to set the position to zero before reading the data : stream.Position = 0;

Comment: Save the image from the database to file to confirm that it is valid, and/or test to store some sequence of bytes to the db and check that it is read correctly. However, using access for anything is probably a bad idea, it is also usually recommended to store images as files, with references in the db. So I'm surprised you have not run into size and compaction issues already. And I would recommend using an *actual* database, like postgres or sqlite.